# appending items from a list to a new list (MS Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, list

Thank you all for helping with my earlier [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261129/creating-a-search-function-in-ms-excel). I have included my next obstacle as a separate thread and hope that doesn't violate any rules/etiquette.

I now have a search facility that creates a list of *potentially* relevant diagnoses:

[image: Potentially relevant diagnoses]

What I'd like to be able to do is work down the list of potentially relevant diagnoses and manually eliminate those that are not relevant by placing a "x" in the adjacent cell. I would then like to press a button and for all checked diagnoses to be appended to a list on another sheet (titled "List"):

[image: Dream list!]

In an ideal world, repeating the search/select/button process would then simply append new diagnoses to the same list, i.e. identify the next blank cell in a column on "List" and carry on from there. One potential difficulty is that I need to copy the diagnosis text out of each cell rather than the formula that's actually there.

Gary's Student has answered a similar [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308914/how-to-add-text-to-last-row-of-a-column) previously with this script but it doesn't quite get me far enough as it takes data from a single cell and doesn't distinguish between text/formulae:

```
Sub ButtonCode()
   Dim N As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Cells(N, "A").Value = Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like I've provided below. Notice that you can grab the cells that you specify by the all the 'x' checkmarks by using the `.Offset` property. Code below:

```
Sub move_diagnoses()
Dim diagnosesheet As Worksheet
Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim last_diagnosis_row As Integer
Dim last_list_row As Integer
Dim loserange As Range
Dim losecell As Range

'Set your worksheets first
Set diagnosesheet = Worksheets("Diagnoses")
'I titled the worksheet you have the diagnoses on as 'Diagnoses' since you didn't specify
Set copysheet = Worksheets("List")

'Now set the range (i.e. collection of cells) that enumerate all the potential diagnoses
'First find the last row in the diagnoses column
'Then find the last used row in the 'List' worksheet
last_diagnosis_row = diagnosesheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
last_list_row = diagnosesheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set loserange = diagnosesheet.Range("D2:D" & last_diagnosis_row)
'Notice the loserange (i.e. the range that contains the all the checkmarks is defined from D2 onwards

For Each losecell In loserange.Cells
    If Trim(losecell.Value) = "x" Then
        copysheet.Cells(last_list_row, 1).Value = losecell.Offset(0, 1).Text
        copysheet.Cells(last_list_row, 2).Value = losecell.Offset(0, 2).Text
        last_list_row = last_list_row + 1
    End If
Next losecell


End Sub
```